# Processing messages from multiple users in a Telegram bot

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, bots, telegram-bot

I can't figure out how to create a bot to process messages from multiple users in parallel.
For example:
User 1 sends a message.
The message is received by the function foo() and processed.
The foo() function returns the processed message
The bot sends the user a processed message.

Messages from user 1, user 2, user 3... must call foo() in parallel and not block each other.

Another problem is this.
I need to block the user from entering a message while the foo() function is being processed.

I can't find any working examples to help me figure it out.

I understand that you need to store the user's state. But how and where? Using global variables (like storing user state in an array) creates queues by blocking threads. Using a DB gives me problems calling and storing state correctly.

I used:
Telebot (synchronous and asynchronous version)
Threads
aiogram3
concurrent.futures
asyncio and various variations of application between them.

But the choice of library for working with Telegram is not important. I need a simple code design. I'm having problems with the algorithm.

Here's my latest code:

```py
import telebot
import time
import random
import concurrent.futures

TOKEN = '123'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

def process_user_data(chat_id, text):
    random_int = random.randint(1, 10)
    time.sleep(random_int)
    response = f"Text - {text}, ID - {chat_id}, wait {random_int} s."
    bot.send_message(chat_id, response)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_messages(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    text = message.text
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.submit(process_user_data, chat_id, text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

It seems to work fine, but sleep() is blocking the threads. What causes a queue to be created.